# how do i read multiple lines as a paragraph

Tags: java

i want to count sequences of line as paragraph i.e. it should count lines without empty spaces between them as 1 line e.g.(paragraph). My code so far count every line without knowing sequences of lines should be counted as 1. Any help on how to come about on this please?

```
     Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/../printout.txt"));

     int count = 0;

     while (file.hasNextLine()){
         file.nextLine();
         count++;
     }
    System.out.println(count);
    file.close();
```

Comment: Besides the naive count above, what have you tried to "catch" that a line is empty, and a new paragraph has started?

Comment: Change the delimiter to two newline characters.

Comment: Is a single line containing just one space an "empty line"? What about two spaces? Thirty-four?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a little state machine, assuming that going from a blank line to a non-blank line signals that you're in a new paragraph:

```
boolean lastWasText = false;
int paragraphCount = 0;
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
  boolean thisIsText = file.nextLine().length() > 0;
  if (!lastWasText && thisIsText) paragraphCount++;
  count++;
  lastWasText = thisIsText;
}
```

If you don't want lines that are all spaces to count, add `trim()` after `nextLine()` and before `length()`.

Comment: ahh clever should have thought of that.thanks a lot for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

**To keep your code**, it should be

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/../printout.txt"));

int count = 0;

while (file.hasNextLine()){
  String line = file.nextLine();
  if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
    count++;
  }
}
System.out.println(count);
file.close();
```

Comment: This counts non-empty lines.  A paragraph consists of multiple non-empty lines, one after another.